# Alias name is same as column name

Tags: sql-server

In sql server 2008 alias name is same as column name so am getting error The column  was specified multiple times.

I can't change the alias name the application breaks

Comment: You probably referencing the column without the alias and with the alias (or are joining on a table that has an identical column name). Can't tell without seeing the query.

Comment: i have posted  the query

Comment: This is not a sql-server problem. This is an issue with your query. Question tagging is not correct.. People would like to see your query before answering

Comment: added the query,can u check the query

Comment: The query has been edited out - consider restoring it.

Answer (score 2):

You have aliased two columns as published.

```
a.published,
```

and

```
CASE a.type
WHEN N'component' THEN a.published+2*(e.enabled-1)
WHEN N'url' THEN a.published+2
WHEN N'alias' THEN a.published+4
WHEN N'separator' THEN a.published+6 END AS published,
```

Comment: It is the column name correct, but you specify it as a column name again in the `case` statement. Change the Case statement column name to `Publish` and it should work

Comment: Thanks Jaques,
So what is the possible solution for the query i renamed alias with a_published it worked but it seems it is not the proper solution

Comment: You will need to identify what the calling process is expecting the "published" field to contain, is it expecting the value stored in a.published or one of the outputs from your case statement i.e. component, url, alias or separator.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return two columns with the same alias.  Each column has to have a unique name.

If you need to return **BOTH** a.published and the result of your `CASE` logic, you need to give one of them a different name.

The calling application is going to ask for the column "published", what do you want to give them as "published"?  As for the other thing, they will have to know to ask for it by a different name.